# "Directory name is invalid." etc. with rabbitmq-plugins on Windows

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-10

I'm trying to get RabbitMQ going on Windows 10 by following [these instructions](http://arcware.net/installing-rabbitmq-on-windows/).

However, when trying to enable the management plugin via powershell command:

```
./rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

I get the following:

```
The directory name is invalid.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Unsupported node name: hostname is invalid (possibly contains unsupported characters).
If using FQDN node names, use the -l / --longnames argument.
```

I've tried setting `HOMEDRIVE=C:` as the blog suggested.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Per the comment below I did the following:

```
PS C:\program files\rabbitmq server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.15\sbin> ./rabbitmq-service.bat stop
The directory name is invalid.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The RabbitMQ service is stopping.
The RabbitMQ service was stopped successfully.

PS C:\program files\rabbitmq server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.15\sbin> ./rabbitmq-service.bat uninstall
The directory name is invalid.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

*********************
Service control usage
*********************

rabbitmq-service help    - Display this help
rabbitmq-service install - Install the RabbitMQ service
rabbitmq-service remove  - Remove the RabbitMQ service

The following actions can also be accomplished by using
Windows Services Management Console (services.msc):

rabbitmq-service start   - Start the RabbitMQ service
rabbitmq-service stop    - Stop the RabbitMQ service
rabbitmq-service disable - Disable the RabbitMQ service
rabbitmq-service enable  - Enable the RabbitMQ service

PS C:\program files\rabbitmq server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.15\sbin> set HOMEDRIVE=C:
PS C:\program files\rabbitmq server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.15\sbin> ./rabbitmq-service.bat install
The directory name is invalid.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
RabbitMQ service is already present - only updating service parameters
"WARNING: Using RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE: C:\Users\Mj\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\advanced.config"
2019-06-14 10:55:09.630000
    args: []
    format: "Failed to create cookie file 'l:/.erlang.cookie': enoent"
    label: {error_logger,error_msg}
2019-06-14 10:55:09.630000 crash_report        #{label=>{proc_lib,crash},report=>[[{initial_call,{auth,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.57.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{error,"Failed to create cookie file 'l:/.erlang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.46.0>]},{message_queue_len,0},{messages,[]},{links,[<0.55.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,27},{reductions,1456}],[]]}
2019-06-14 10:55:09.635000 supervisor_report   #{label=>{supervisor,start_error},report=>[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{"Failed to create cookie file 'l:/.erlang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{id,auth},{mfargs,{auth,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
2019-06-14 10:55:09.704000 supervisor_report   #{label=>{supervisor,start_error},report=>[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Failed to create cookie file 'l:/.erlang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{id,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
2019-06-14 10:55:09.742000 crash_report        #{label=>{proc_lib,crash},report=>[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.45.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Failed to create cookie file 'l:/.erlang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,138}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.44.0>]},{message_queue_len,1},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.46.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.44.0>,<0.43.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,27},{reductions,184}],[]]}
2019-06-14 10:55:09.789000 std_info            #{label=>{application_controller,exit},report=>[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Failed to create cookie file 'l:/.erlang.cookie': enoent",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,"auth.erl"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{\"Failed to create cookie file 'l:/.erlang.cookie': enoent\",[{auth,init_cookie,0,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,286}]},{auth,init,1,[{file,\"auth.erl\"},{line,140}]},{gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,374}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,342}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,249}]}]}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,auth,{"Failed to create cookie file 'l:/.er

Crash dump is being written to: C:\Users\Mj\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log\erl_crash.dump...done
```

Comment: Try this: log in as the admin user you installed RMQ with, open the "RabbitMQ Command Prompt (sbin dir)" terminal, run `.\rabbitmq-service.bat stop`, `.\rabbitmq-service.bat uninstall`, `set HOMEDRIVE=C:`, `.\rabbitmq-service.bat install`, `.\rabbitmq-service.bat start`, `.\rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management`. Also see - https://stackoverflow.com/q/56364372/1466825

Comment: Oddly, when stopping the service, I get: `The directory name is invalid.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The RabbitMQ service is stopping.
The RabbitMQ service was stopped successfully.`. I uninstalled, set the HOMEDRIVE, and installed. Got a massive error listing.

Comment: Updated post with attempt per comment above.

Comment: `format: "Failed to create cookie file 'l:/.erlang.cookie': enoent"` - ensure that `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` both use `C:`. Or, create a local admin user. Domain users seem to have problems like these.

Comment: Thanks, @LukeBakken. I think I'll punt and just move to linux. That seems to be the more-traveled path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based off of the comment @LukeBakken made in the original question, I was able to get around this by creating a local admin user and doing the install under the local admin user. This was after hours of battling by setting the HOMEDRIVE, etc.

Comment: It works for me :)
1 uninstall rebbitmq
2 login using local admin "Administrator" account
3 insall rabbitmq 
4 enable rebbitmq_management

Answer (score 9):

Seems that the Order at which the commands are ran Matters, this worked for me, shuffle them around

```
SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
rabbitmq-service.bat stop
rabbitmq-service.bat install
rabbitmq-service.bat start
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by following way :
1. Opened command prompt using administrative mode
2. Go to sbin directory. Execute command "SET HOMEDRIVE=C:"

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment from Luke Bakken, this is what worked for me:

Almost the same as his comment, but instead of `uninstall` I had to use `remove`. `uninstall` was not recognized.

"Log in as the admin user you installed RMQ with; Open the "RabbitMQ Command Prompt (sbin dir)" terminal, run:"

```
.\rabbitmq-service.bat stop
.\rabbitmq-service.bat remove
set HOMEDRIVE=C: 
.\rabbitmq-service.bat install
.\rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
.\rabbitmq-service.bat start
```