# Unable to start plugins for RabbitMQ

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, erlang

I'm new to windows and rabbit mq and I'm unable to start web management plugin. I followed the steps listed [here](https://cmatskas.com/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-windows/) but I get this message.

```
PS C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.0\sbin> .\rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management
The directory name is invalid.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Unsupported node name: hostname is invalid (possibly contains unsupported characters).
If using FQDN node names, use the -l / --longnames argument.
```

I also have the `ERLANG_HOME` variable, that was created during installation.
[image]

Please advise

Comment: `Unsupported node name: hostname is invalid (possibly contains unsupported characters).` You don't share your user name or host name so I can't confirm that is the reason.

Comment: Where can I find what hostname is being used?

Comment: What is the output of the `hostname` command? What is the output of the following command when run in a `cmd.exe` shell. If `erl.exe` is not in your PATH you will have to `cd` first to `C:\Program Files\erl*\bin` - `erl.exe -A0 -noinput -boot start_clean -eval "net_kernel:start([list_to_atom(""rabbit-gethostname-"" ++ os:getpid()), shortnames]), [_, H] = string:tokens(atom_to_list(node()), ""@""), io:format(""~s~n"", [H]), init:stop()."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue in this case was the `HOMEPATH`. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601031/directory-name-is-invalid-etc-with-rabbitmq-plugins-on-windows) post, I set it using `HOMEDRIVE=C:` and it worked.